# git non-fast-forward error

Tags: git

I've reverted to a previous version of my commit then I've done some other commits but without pushing to the remote repo.

When I do push I got the following error:

To git@xxxxxx
 ! [rejected]        REPO -> REPO (non-fast-forward)
error: failed to push some refs to '.....'
To prevent you from losing history, non-fast-forward updates were rejected
Merge the remote changes (e.g. 'git pull') before pushing again.  See the
'Note about fast-forwards' section of 'git push --help' for details.

Yet, when I do a pull, I get repo up to date.
Please help, I cannot integrate my work.

Comment: What exact command are you using to push and pull? Which local and remote branches?

Comment: Copied from your error: "See the 'Note about fast-forwards' section of 'git push --help' for details."

Answer (score 7):

`git push --force`

"Usually, the command refuses to update a remote ref that is not an ancestor of the local ref used to overwrite it. This flag disables the check. This can cause the remote repository to lose commits; use it with care."